# How to use query push using useRouter in NextJS 13 App Router?

Tags: routes, next.js, next.js13

In new App router, I tried this

```
<button onClick={() => {
   router.push('/donate/payment?amount=20')
 }}>Donate</button>
```

and this

```
<button onClick={() => {
   router.push({
      pathname: '/donate/payment',
      query: { amount:20 }
    })
 }}>Donate</button>
```

but neither of this work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `type="button"` to your button element. If your button resides inside a form, click event would trigger form submission and chances are your current page would just reload.

This should work:

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

export default function Test() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <button
      type="button" 
      onClick={() => router.push("/donate/payment?amount=20")}
    >
      Donate
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `Router` from `next/router`. I'm not sure, from where you have imported `router` in your code.

**Note** - Please make a note that the first letter of Router is capitalized.

```
import Router from 'next/router';

<button onClick={() => {
   Router.push({
      pathname: '/donate/payment',
      query: { amount:20 }
    })
 }}>Donate</button>
```

Comment: How does `next/router` work with the new app router?

Comment: It doesn't work with the new app router: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-router-not-mounted

Comment: Downvote as the question specifically refers to the App Router and not Pages Router which is what `import Router from 'next/router';` is for.